# Spark Structured Streaming: Aggregate rows into columns without watermarking

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following two parquet schemas:

```
users:
--------------------
|user_id | username|
|--------|---------|
|  1     |  micky  |
|  2     |  minnie |
|__3_____|__donald_|

orders:
--------------------
|user_id | order_id|
|--------|---------|
|  1     |  411    |
|  2     |  412    |
|  3     |  413    |
|  1     |  414    |
|  2     |  415    |
|  3     |  416    |
|  3     |  471    |
|  3     |  482    |
|__3_____|__500____|
```

What I'm trying to do is to collect all orders for the customer into a single column:

```
users_and_orders
-------------------------------------------
|user_id | username| orders               |
|--------|---------|-------- --------------
|  1     |  micky  | [411,414]            |
|  2     |  minnie | [412,415]            |
|__3_____|__donald_| [413,416,471,482,500]|
```

The code looks like the below:

```scala
val users = sparkSession.readStream.option("checkpointLocation", "somelocation")
  .schema(userSchema.asInstanceOf[StructType])
  .format("parquet")
  .load(commandLineArguments.userPath)
  .distinct()

val orders = sparkSession
  .read
  .option("checkpointLocation", "someOtherLocation")
  .schema(orderSchema.asInstanceOf[StructType])
  .format("parquet")
  .load(commandLineArguments.orderPath)



val userJoinOrders = users.join(orders, Seq("user_id"))

val currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMM").format(new Date())
val currentTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmm")
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMMDD")
val systemDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDHHmmss")



//Original data does not have watermark/timestamp
val usersWithOrders = userJoinOrders
  .withColumn("timestamp", lit(unix_timestamp(date_format(current_timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm").cast("timestamp")))
  .withWatermark("timestamp","10 minutes")
  .groupBy("user_id","username","timestamp")
  .agg(collect_set(struct($"order_id")) as "orders")
  .map(account => {
    //Do whatever
})
```

As I understand, since I'm aggregating on streaming data it requires a watermark. The original data does not have any watermark. So I had to make one up. But the above doesn't work. When I run the streaming code, in the output I see:

```
Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "5f31d025-712e-4577-b6d7-8e8d450ac926",
  "runId" : "643fe17a-979a-4599-ac94-45be60136350",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2019-01-21T11:07:22.922Z",
  "batchId" : 0,
  "numInputRows" : 856,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 52.42207116173679,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 15222,
    "getBatch" : 44,
    "getOffset" : 45,
    "queryPlanning" : 888,
    "triggerExecution" : 16329,
    "walCommit" : 51
  },
  "eventTime" : {
    "avg" : "2019-01-21T11:07:00.000Z",
    "max" : "2019-01-21T11:07:00.000Z",
    "min" : "2019-01-21T11:07:00.000Z",
    "watermark" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ {
    "numRowsTotal" : 856,
    "numRowsUpdated" : 856,
    "memoryUsedBytes" : 805831,
    "customMetrics" : {
      "loadedMapCacheHitCount" : 0,
      "loadedMapCacheMissCount" : 0,
      "stateOnCurrentVersionSizeBytes" : 777031
    }
  }, {
    "numRowsTotal" : 856,
    "numRowsUpdated" : 856,
    "memoryUsedBytes" : 659463,
    "customMetrics" : {
      "loadedMapCacheHitCount" : 0,
      "loadedMapCacheMissCount" : 0,
      "stateOnCurrentVersionSizeBytes" : 630663
    }
  } ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "FileStreamSource[file:/blah/blah/blah]",
    "startOffset" : null,
    "endOffset" : {
      "logOffset" : 0
    },
    "numInputRows" : 856,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 52.42207116173679
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "FileSink[/blah/blah/blah/user-orders]"
  }
}
```

My question:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way to convert associated
   rows into column values and not having to use aggregate/group by?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.